# Delete rows from data base table

Tags: c#, database, linq, linq-to-sql

I have member m_WeightScaleEntities:

```
private static WeightScaleEntities m_WeightScaleEntities = new WeightScaleEntities();
```

This member holdes my data base.
This member contain User_Activity table
I want to delete rows from that table by given id.

I get the rows to be delete like that:

```
var deleteUserActivities = from details in m_WeightScaleEntities.User_Activity
                           where details.Id == i_UserActivityId
                           select details;
```

Now, i want to delete this rows from the data base table.
How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what i needed to do after the query:

```
foreach (var item in deleteUserActivities)
{
     m_WeightScaleEntities.DeleteObject(item);
}
And then SaveChanges() on the object context.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
User_Activity.DeleteAllOnSubmit(deleteUserActivities);
contextName.SubmitChanges();
```

use the above code.  Replace context name with the name of your database context object.

Comment: i know this technique, but the problem is that i dont have the method DeleteOnSubmit! i cant do m_WeightScaleEntities.User_Activity.DeleteOnSubmit

Answer (score 0):

Well, apparently your WeightScaleEntities class is not the datacontext.

So you need to add a delete method to this class and implement the datacontext.DeleteAllOnSubmit there.

Or perhaps your WeightScaleEntities implements something like GetContext or has the context publically available.

Bottom line: talk with the developers of your WeightScaleEntities and implement it there...

Comment: and why are you having WeightScaleEntities anyway?

Comment: This is my connection to the data base. he holds all my tables

Comment: WeightScaleEntities : EntityObject (derived)